# List with transparent png sprite as background image click glitch

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using a png sprite with a transparent background as button art in a list.

```
.single-pdsh #navlist li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    opacity: .15;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.single-pdsh #navlist li:hover,
.single-pdsh #navlist li:active,
.single-pdsh #navlist li:visited {
    opacity: .25;
}
.single-pdsh #navlist li, .single-pdsh #navlist a {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    display: block;
}
.single-pdsh li#prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 5px;
    background: url('https://kidconqueror.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone-child/images/nav_sprite_800x800.png');
    background-size: 300px 300px;
    background-position: -10px 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Button works as expected. Almost. Hover triggers opacity transition as designed.

However, after clicking the button, before page transition, the background of the list item appears. I've exaggerated it a little here for clarity.

Why is this happening?

Screenshot of glitch:

[image: Screenshot]

Sprite button art png:

[image: sprite art]

Comment: Hello @markw the given link is not contain any

Comment: Yeah, not surprised, wp site is set to private. Edited url out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly, I switched from a Wordpress child theme based on Twenty Twenty One to one based on WP Bootstrap Starter and the weird effect went away. No clue why except that maybe bootstrap represents a more modern code base?